# Understanding what does Axios create do

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, quasar

I was asked to make API call to send data.

On Click in vue, I was firing this event

```
async facebookDataToSend () {
  let campaignID = await this.$store.getters['CurrentInstance/id']
  this.$axios.post(process.env.API_BASE_URL + 'faceeBookCampaign', { campaignID: campaignID }, { withCredentials: true })
},
```

But then, I was told to use API functions which already exsist in some xyz.js file.

My xyz.js file looks like this..

```
const rest = {
  something: axios.create({
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    withCredentials: true
  }),
  setClient: function (client) {
    this.something = axios.create({
      baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
      withCredentials: true,
      params: {
        __somethingClient: client
      }
    })
    this.client = client
  }
}
```

Here, I am unable to comprehend how can I use this instance to make an api call So I viewed the code where they have already made the api call and saw something like this

```
const API = {
  url: '/whateverHtml/',
        method: 'post',
        withCredentials: true,
        data: {
          'schemaType': 'something-event', // TODO FIXME
          'field': 'description', // TODO FIXME
          'html': this.model[this.field.key]
        }
api.something.request(API).then(result => {
```

And I wasn't able to comprehend the code. For starters

What is request? I don't see my any method or property inside `something` in my `rest` variable

second why are they using  `withCredentials: true` in their `API` object when they have already set up the property as true in `rest` object]

What are the pro's of using `axios.create({` i.e what they are doing than what I initially did `this.$axios.post(`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request` is a method defined by `axios`. Link to [docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config).

`request` allows you to make an HTTP call with any verb you want (POST, GET, DELETE, PUT). Most likely axios calls `request` from inside all the other helper methods (`get`, `post`), but this is an implementation details. One of the advantages of using `request` is that you don't have to hardcode the HTTP verb (POST, GET ...) and you can set it at run time depending on your input.

I see 2 reasons why they would set `withCredentials`:

- `setClient` may or may not be called before `something`
- for clarity: it's enough to look at the definition of `something` to realise that the client is using credentials and you don't need any extra information about how `rest` works.

I don't think the request for you to use `something` boils down to advantages of `axios.$post` vs `axios.create`. It's probably related more to how to organise your code.

Some advantages of using a separate module vs calling `axios` directly

- when calling axios directly you are prepending base url all the time, when using a module for your REST API the base URL is tucked away and arguably makes your code easier to read
- you can bake other options inside config and make sure they are used. For instance you may have an access token, the module can store that token and always added to any request. When calling axios by hand you need to remember this
- you are decoupled from axios (to some degree)(1). When using a module you don't actually care if it's axios doing the requests or not.
- You can add more API calls to the module that you can reuse in the future. I'm expecting `xyz` file to grow in time and your call to `faceeBookCampaign` to end up being a method on the `rest` variable. It makes more sense to end up using `this.client` and not `something` but this is up to the devs.
- it keeps all the REST API calls in one place allowing you to build an SDK for that API, which as the project grows can have its own life cycle.

(1) I say that id decouples you to some degree because there are semantics that need to be kept so everything works. The returned object needs to have a request method that accepts a config object. The config need to conform to the same structure as the one that axios wants. But, you can always write an [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) for that, so you are actually decoupled from axios.

Answer (score 0):

`request` here takes a config and returns a promise. I am guessing this approach is usually taken when you want to reuse a request object that is created using `create` (at least my sense).

I feel the `request` method is used to overwrite the initial configuration with new one defined in `API`. And, the double `withCredentials` should be an oversight. 
OR, because API is defining a new config object, therefore when defined without `withCredentials`, it would overwrite the `create`'s configuration.

Hence, it looks like its specified twice.